# TextBox keypress event when backspace is press in C#

Tags: c#, keypress, backspace

It should delete the last character of string

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        do
        {
```

this section write character in the textbox

```
            if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
            {
                textBox1.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString();
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
            }
```

this is the backspace part that doesn't work

```
            if(e.KeyChar == 8)
            {
                sssnumber = textBox1.Text;
                sssnumber.Remove(sssnumber.Length - 1);
                textBox1.Text = sssnumber;
            }

        } while (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
            (e.KeyChar != '.'));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you to use KeyDown event, it gives you more control. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you not just return out of your keypress if the backspace is used, thus preserving the keys actual function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this code is that you are not assigning the string's value when you change it. This is because `String.Remove()` returns a string as opposed to changing the string directly

```
sssnumber.Remove(sssnumber.Length - 1);
```

Will remove the character from the end of the string, and then dispose of the result

```
sssnumber = sssnumber.Remove(sssnumber.Length - 1);
```

On the other hand, will do the same, but then set the value of `sssnumber` to the removed value.

Comment: @AdrianManuelCleofe Glad I could help! you can accept the answer if it worked for you